# the canvas onDraw does not show enything

Tags: android, canvas, android-view

I want to have a canvas to edit the photos.i get the photo from gallery and send it to my customize View.but i dont kmow how to set the photo in canvas:
heres my code:

```
public class CanvasView extends View {
    ImageView img;
    Bitmap canvasBitmap;
    Canvas drawCanvas;

    public CanvasView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
    public void setCanvasPath(String bitmap_path) {
        BitmapFactory.Options decode_options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        decode_options.inMutable = true;
        canvasBitmap  = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(bitmap_path,decode_options);

        drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);

        drawCanvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        invalidate();
    }
    @Override

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }
}
```

this is the xml file:

```
    <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?-->
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are drawing the Bitmap on the wrong canvas

```
  protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (canvasBitmap != null) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, null);
        }
  }
```

Comment: i changed the code but still nothing show.the canvasBitmap isn't null.i edit the code.

Comment: how are you using your CanvasView? Isn't declared in your layout. Are you adding to it programmatically ?